# Ant Design - Right arrow on horiozontal menu

Tags: antd

This is the base ANT horizintal menu:

[image: Base ANT menu]

The Navigation Threes has a sub-menu but the layout of an element with submenu is the same as menu, so it's impossible for the user understand that this menu, has sub elements.

I would like to add an arrow on right (like in vertical). There is a configuration for that, or i need to modify some CSS ?

Desidered result:[image]

Comment: I am also having a problem close to this if not similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76660496/how-to-change-antd-table-header-order-in-react). Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these styles to your css file, because in horizontal mode and has not added :before and after to .ant-menu-submenu-arrow class.

```
.ant-menu-submenu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-left > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-right > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 16px;
    width: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transition: -webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1), -webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
}

.ant-menu-submenu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after, .ant-menu-submenu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-left > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-left > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-right > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-right > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 6px;
    height: 1.5px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .85)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .85)));
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85), rgba(0, 0, 0, .85));
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1), top .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1), -webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transition: background .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1), top .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1), -webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transition: background .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1), transform .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1), top .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transition: background .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1), transform .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1), top .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1), -webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    content: "";
}

.ant-menu-submenu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-left > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-right > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-2px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-2px);
}

.ant-menu-submenu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-left > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-right > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(2px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(2px);
}

.ant-menu-submenu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-title:hover .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after, .ant-menu-submenu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-title:hover .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-left > .ant-menu-submenu-title:hover .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-left > .ant-menu-submenu-title:hover .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-right > .ant-menu-submenu-title:hover .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-right > .ant-menu-submenu-title:hover .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical > .ant-menu-submenu-title:hover .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical > .ant-menu-submenu-title:hover .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#1890ff), to(#1890ff));
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #1890ff, #1890ff);
}

.ant-menu-submenu-vertical-left > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-right > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-2px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-2px);
}

.ant-menu-submenu-vertical-left > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical-right > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after, .ant-menu-submenu-vertical > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(2px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(2px);
}

.ant-menu-submenu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(2px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(2px);
}

.ant-menu-submenu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-2px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-2px);
}

.ant-menu-submenu-open.ant-menu-submenu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.ant-menu-submenu-open.ant-menu-submenu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-2px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-2px);
}

.ant-menu-submenu-open.ant-menu-submenu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-title .ant-menu-submenu-arrow:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(2px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(2px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is you can remove the `icon` on `Submenu` and place it on the `title` props (it accepts react node)

```
<SubMenu
    key="SubMenu"
    title={
        <span>
            Navigation Three - Submenu <DownOutlined />
        </span>
    }
>
    //menu items
</SubMenu>
```

[image: Edit]

Comment: with this solution we should set top arrow as well and miss the animation.

Answer (score 0):

u can add it to your items Object Array in the menu items.

```
label: (
  <div>
    Launchpad <DownOutlined />
  </div>
),
```