# How to change antd table header order in react

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am working on a react app with antd tables. What I am trying to achieve is change column order using the left and right arrows as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Any idea how this can be achieved in react using functional component?

Currently my table looks like this:
[image]

And here is the code that I am using:

```
<Table
  columns={columns}
  style={{ marginTop: 8, height: 500 }}
  pagination={false}
  dataSource={newDataSource}
  onRow={(record, recordIndex) => ({
    onClick: () => rowClick(record)
  })}
  rowSelection={rowSelection}
  size="small"
  components={vt}
  scroll={{ y: 440, x: 1450 }}
  sticky
  rowKey={(row) => row.id}
  rowClassName={(record) => !record.enabled && 'disabled-row'}
/>
```

Columns:

```
const columns = [
  {
    dataIndex: 'country',
    title: (
  <p style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
    COUNTRY
    <CaretRightOutlined onClick={() => alert('Move RIght')} style={{ marginLeft: 130 }} />
  </p>
),
    width: '10%',
    ellipsis: true
  },
  {
    dataIndex: 'market_name',
    title: (
  <p style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
    <CaretLeftOutlined onClick={() => alert('Move left')} /> MARKET
    <CaretRightOutlined onClick={() => alert('Move RIght')} style={{ marginLeft: 230 }} />
  </p>
),
    width: '15%',
    ellipsis: true
  },
  {
    dataIndex: 'product_name',
   title: (
  <p style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
    <CaretLeftOutlined onClick={() => alert('Move left')} /> PRODUCT
    <CaretRightOutlined onClick={() => alert('Move RIght')} style={{ marginLeft: 330 }} />
  </p>
),
    width: '20%',
    ellipsis: true
  }
]
```

Comment: you should at least provide the code man

Answer (score 0):

The order of the table column can be changed by swapping the elements(index) of the "columns" array for the action of the left or right arrow.

There is a probability to mutate the array. In such case, make a copy of the "columns" array and render or do the rest of your work or functionalities using this copied array.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet for this solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple demo

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { Table } from "antd";
import { CaretLeftOutlined, CaretRightOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const swap = (arr, a, b) => {
  const tmp = arr[a];
  arr[a] = arr[b];
  arr[b] = tmp;
};

function AntdTableColMove() {

  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);

  const handleColMoveLeft = (colName) => () => {
    const idx = columns.findIndex((v) => v === colName);
    if (idx === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const newCols = columns.slice();
    swap(newCols, idx, idx - 1);
    setColumns(newCols);
  };

  const handleColMoveRight = (colName) => () => {
    const idx = columns.findIndex((v) => v === colName);
    if (idx === columns.length - 1) {
      return;
    }
    const newCols = columns.slice();
    swap(newCols, idx, idx + 1);
    setColumns(newCols);
  };

  const tableColums = useMemo(() => {
    return columns.map(v => ({
      dataIndex: v,
      title: (
        <>
          <CaretLeftOutlined
            onClick={handleColMoveLeft(v)}
          />
          {v.toUpperCase()}
          <CaretRightOutlined
            onClick={handleColMoveRight(v)}
          />
        </>
      )
    }))
  }, [columns])

  const dataSource = [
    {
      country: 'US',
      market_name: 'aaa',
      product_name: 'apple',
    },
    {
      country: 'UK',
      market_name: 'bbb',
      product_name: 'banana',
    },
    {
      country: 'DE',
      market_name: 'ccc',
      product_name: 'orange',
    },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    let init = false
    if (!init) {
      setColumns(['country', 'market_name', 'product_name']);
    }
    return () => {
      init = true
    }
  }, []);

  return <Table rowKey={"country"} columns={tableColums} dataSource={dataSource} />;
}
```

Output like this:
[Antd Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4WGE.png)